# LibGDX : Model, Node, Mesh, MeshPart architecture

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm kinda new to LibGDX, and trying to understand the basic Model system, with nodes, meshes etc. After hours spent reading the wiki or looking at the documentation, I would like to know if I'm right.

A Model (that can be rendered using a ModelInstance) is composed by many Node's. A Node is basically kind of an abstract concept, it's a set of data, containing a position, rotation and scale value. It also contains a globalTransform variable (a Matrix4 instance), and using this matrix to set the position / rotation / scale by using `Matrix4#setToTranslation` will set the position of the Node in the current World. Although, using the position vector in the Node directly doesn't change the world position.

Then, each Node can have children. These children can be other `Node`'s, `NodePart`'s (= MeshPart + Material) or `MeshPart`'s. A MeshPart is a subset of vertices coming from a Mesh. To add a MeshPart to the Node, we can create a MeshPart with a `MeshBuilder` using the `part` method. To add a NodePart, we can create a ModelBuilder and use the `part` method.

Our Model finished, we can create a ModelInstance, either by putting the entire model in a ModelInstance (`new ModelInstance(model)` ) or by specifying which node of the Model we want to use in our ModelInstance. Then we call the render method from a ModelBatch to display our ModelInstance.

As a conclusion, The relationship between Model and Node is "the same" as the one between Node and NodePart, and the same as the one between Mesh and MeshPart

Are my assumptions correct ? I'm not sure if I'm right at this point : "We can add a MeshPart to the Node as a child"

Thank you very much for reading !

Askigh

Comment: I think everything you say is correct. But if you're planning to use LibGDX for 3D stuff, don't. There's way too little documentation. A great alternative would be jMonkeyEngine.

Comment: I don't think the documentation is that poor, and there are a lot of examples that we can easily find, such as the xoppa tutorials. Surely jMonkeyEngine has more but..... I'll see. (edit : I looked at some jmonkey code the concepts look quite similar. It could change my mind) Thanks for you reply !